# Install 32 bit version of libmrm on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, shared-library, motif

I am trying to run a 32 bit program on 64 bit Ubuntu 22.04. The program has dependency on the libmrm4 library.

I am trying to install the 32-bit version of the libmrm4 library in 22.04.

I added the 32-bit arch support in ubuntu using

> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
> sudo apt-get install multiarch-support

However when I try to install the 32-bit version of libmrm4, I still get an error:

> apt install libmrm4:i386
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree... Done
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package libmrm4:i386

Please let me know how I can solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: 22.04 doesn't have a 32bit version in the repositories. Adding an architecture does not magically provide packages. Where would "libmrm4:i386" come from?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I believe 22.04 does have access to 32-bit repositories. Doing a sudo apt update does reveal those 32-bit repositories. I am also able to install 32-bit packages of various other packages by postfixing :386 to those packages. But cannot seem to find the libmrm:i386 package. Theoretically a 64-bit platform should be able to run a 32-bit platform if it has access to all the relevant 32-bit libraries.

Comment: There is a limited set of 32 bit packages mostly related to Steam. `libmrm4:i386` is most definitely not available. Ubuntu discontinued 32bit support in 2019, 19.04 being the last release.

Comment: Thanks. If the 32-bit version of libmrm4 is not available in the repos, would it be possible to retrieve the 32-bit libraries from 19.04 and manually install them in 22.04? Would that work?

Comment: I hope it will work. Try and let us know. :~)

Comment: Update: I was able to install the 32-bit libraries of libmrm4 in 22.10. They have it in their repos.

Comment: After doing sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 I cannot locate a package by the name of multiarch-support.  A search on the Ubuntu package search https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=multiarch-support&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all fails to find any such package